# In my IP query, the response is "SOA prisoner." What does this mean?

Tags: google, dns, server, ip-address, whois

what does "SOA prisoner" mean in the results of my IP query? Prisoner to what ?

Comment: How are you querying the IP? What are you using and the full command if any? It may help to know the IP address too. This will help us to know better how to answer your question.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller You are right to put this one hold. I was going to wait- then I got curious. As it turns out, with the right Google query, this is a question that can be answered from several sources, though many of them are technical. So I entered an answer anyway. It may not fully answer the users question, but it will get them started.

Comment: Your answer is fine and helpful, clasetnoc.  I'd be glad to re-open this question when we get more info from the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information I found:

Here is the Google query I used: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=DNS+SOA+prisoner

From Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259922

This may help: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/prisoner-iana-org-t2262340.html

This is a ServerFault answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/509364/what-is-the-structure-of-zones-synthesized-by-binds-empty-zones-enable-feature

This may help: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/nanog/users/90345

Essentially, it looks like private IP addresses are used on your network that are not resolving using your DNS. If you have your own DNS, some zones need to added that are likely missing. For Windows, there are other solutions.

I only picked a few of the items that appear to have good answers to at least get you started. You may need to search around a bit more if you are not running your own DNS and not using Windows.